# jQuery not loading, new to this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to this and I can't seem to get the jQuery to load. I am trying to toggle the class on an item identified by id.

The goal is to have the clicked item to have the class "menu-selected' and the item to have the class "unselected"

I believe I've placed all the relevant HTML below. It may be that I've made a mistake in my HTML or CSS, though it is working no differently than before I attempted to add JS.

Did I import jQuery incorrectly?

Did I write the script correctly?

Is my order of operations/placement correct?

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#left-cafe').click(function(){
                $('#left-cafe').removeClass('unselected');
                $('#left-cafe').addClass('menu-selected');
                $('#left-breakfast').removeClass('menu-selected');
                $('#left-breakfast').addClass('unselected');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .left-menu{
            background-color:rgb(200,200,200);
            display:block;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            height:50px;
        }
        .left-menu-list{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        .left-menu-list li{
            display:block;
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            height:100%;
            font-size:35px;
            line-height:75px;
            }
        .menu-selected{
            background-color:rgb(150,150,150);
        }
        .unselected{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="left-menu"> <!-- Start left-menu -->
            <ul class="left-menu-list">
                <li class="menu-selected" id="left-cafe">Cafe</li>
                <li class="unselected" id="left-breakfast">Breakfast</li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End left-menu -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Initially there is no `unselected` class to remove from  #left-cafe.

Comment: use `toggleClass` to toggle the class. you're tying to remove and add same class `unselected` in left-breakfast

Comment: JQuery is loaded, you can simplify your script: http://jsfiddle.net/ete4ohjo/ On page load - you already have class 'menu-selected' on first item, and 'unselected' on second item - so, logic is wrong.... p.s. unselected class is not needed, actually...

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't have any jQuery error. But there is logic error.

```js
       
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#left-cafe').click(function(){
         
          $('#left-cafe').toggleClass(' menu-selected unselected');
               
          $('#left-breakfast').toggleClass(' menu-selected unselected');
     });
});
```

```css
 .left-menu {
     background-color:rgba(200, 200, 200,1);
     display:block;
     float:left;
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
 }
 .left-menu-list {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
 }
 .left-menu-list li {
     display:block;
     float:left;
     width:20%;
     height:100%;
     font-size:35px;
     line-height:75px;
 }
 .menu-selected {
     background-color:rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
 }
 .unselected {
     display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="left-menu">
        <!-- Start left-menu -->
        <ul class="left-menu-list">
            <li class="menu-selected" id="left-cafe">Cafe</li>
            <li class="unselected" id="left-breakfast">Breakfast</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

You are trying to remove and add same class again. So there is no difference in your output. Instead you must toggle the class.

Comment: Upvote for this answer because you actually give the reason.. Not just say "here is the correct code" without explaining it..

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in your script:
just replace your JAVASCRIPT code with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#left-cafe,#left-breakfast').click(function () {
        $(".menu-selected").removeClass("menu-selected").addClass("unselected");
        $(this).addClass("menu-selected");
    });
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvy2w3f7/)

Comment: The class for breakfast is not toggling. Its same :)

Comment: @mohamedrias
does toggle required, I feel OP wrote that `toggle` word by mistake, because if you click on same menu again then it should remain selected... right?